# Lucene, certain keywords in queries (e.g. "TO" in range queries) are case sensitive

Tags: lucene

In Lucene, searches look case-insensitive to the user by default due to the standard analyzer. That is what users expect, and that works fine.

However, for a few words like "TO" in range queries, or "AND"/"OR", those keywords are case sensitive. That's not what user's expect.

1. Is there a reason for this? Lucene basically "just works" by default so am a little surprised by that. Maybe there's a good reason behind it and I shouldn't touch it.
2. How would I go about making those keywords case insensitive? As the rest of the query is case insensitive by default, I could just convert the entire query to uppercase? Are there any problems I'm going to encounter if I do that? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there a reason for this?**

The real question here might not be "why does lucene do this?", but rather ["why does google do this?"](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en), as I believe Google's use of this pattern predates Lucene's.  Regardless, though, the reasoning isn't too hard to deduce.  There needs to be a way of differentiating the word "and" from the the query operator "AND".

Say my query is: `Jack and Jill went up the hill`

I'm just searching a phrase that happens to contain the word "and".  The end result *I* want is (eliminating stop words, and such):

```
field:jack field:jill field:went field:up field:hill
```

Rather than:

```
+field:jack +field:jill field:went field:up field:hill
```

If the word is uppercased, it's a decent indicator the user intended the word as an operator.

If all ands became operands, users might be confused why a search for "bread and butter pickles" (becomes `+bread +butter pickles`) turns up hits about toast, but not about other types of pickles.

Similar for lists of things, like "Abby, Ben, Chris, Dave and Elmer" (becomes `abby ben chris +dave +elmer`), which all hits would *require* Dave and Elmer to be present, but the rest of the names would be optional.

---

**How to make them case insensitive?**

Uppercasing the whole thing, or every instance of an `AND`, `OR` or `TO`, could be a bit promblematic.  Take these, for example:

- `[to TO tz]` works, `[TO TO TZ]` throws an exception
- `and another thing` works, `AND ANOTHER THING` throws an exception

You could check for a `ParseException` after uppercasing, and try parsing the original query in that case.  Might create a bit of an inconsistency, but it beats just failing entirely.